# Using ODBTP from Linux client to MSSQL - response error

Tags: php, sql-server, adodb

I have MSSQL running on a Windows server. I can connect to it using ODBTP, ADODB and PHP from other windows servers. When I try the same thing on a Linux server, I get a response error:
`[ODBTPERR][0]Invalid Response in /var/www/html/Database/adodb5/drivers/adodb-mssql.inc.php on line 726:[ODBTPERR][0]Invalid Response`
The ODBTP (v1.1.4) is enabled as an extension on the Linux server, and if I play with the odbtp.conf file settings I get proper connection errors, so it is picking things up correctly.
I can telnet from the Linux server to the database server on port 2799 and get back an OBDTP prompt.
Can anyone suggest any steps? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem:
PHP Warning:  [ODBTPERR][0]Invalid Response in /var/projects/myproject/tmptest.php on line 16

And I also solved it by recompiling odbtp. 
Here are detailed instructions from README.64bitOS file found in odbtp source directory (odbtp-1.1.4)

### Building ODBTP client library on a 64-bit OS

On 64-bit operating systems, suzh as Tru64 UNIX, the C intrinsic data
type "long" is 64 bits.  However, the ODBTP client library assumes
that the "long" data type is 32 bits.  If the client library is built
on a 64-bit system using the "out of the box" configuration,  then
"Invalid Response" errors will occur during client application runtime.
To prevent these errors from occuring, _C_LONG_64_ must be defined
prior to compiling the library. This is doen by simply uncommenting the
line in the file odbtp.h that defines this symbol

Instructions:

1. Open the file odbtp.h in a plain text editor, such as vi.
2. Find the line containing the _C_LONG_64_ definition that has
   been "commented out".

   /* #define _C_LONG_64_ 1 */
3. Uncomment the line by removing the /* and */.

   #define _C_LONG_64_ 1
4. Exit the editor, and then build the client library according
   to the installation instructions.

---

I am not sure if this solution would work with static ODBTP extension... I have implemented it using dynamic extension (http://odbtp.sourceforge.net/install.html#phpshared)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by trying to use odbtp libraries and php extension that were not compiled for a 64bit machine. This clue came from a Robert Twitty posting on a forum (not sure where). We recompiled the libodbtp.so and odbtp.so enabled for 64 bits. The solution was found by Dave Keen (dev@ruffness.com).